# Proving the inverse of a piecewise function

Tags: functions

I have function $f:[0,\infty) \longrightarrow [0, \infty) $ such that

$ f(x)=\begin{cases} 
      x-1 & x \in [1,\infty) \\
      0 & x \in [0,1) \\
   \end{cases}
$

Is this function $\lbrace g:[0,\infty) \longrightarrow [0, \infty) \: \vert \: g(x)=x+1 \rbrace$ the inverse?

I know that $f$ is bijective, and I have calculated the inverse of $f$ to be:

$ f^{-1}(x)=\begin{cases} 
      x+1 & x \in [0,\infty) \\
      0 & x \in [0,0) \\
   \end{cases}
$

which matches $g(x) = x+1$ for $x \in [0,\infty)$, however, a point $0$ still exists for $x \in [0,0)$. Does the inclusion of this point mean that $g$ is not the inverse of $f$?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $f(x)=0$ for all $x \in [0,1)$ the function is not injective and so it has no inverse.

Comment: Oh how did I miss that! Thank you